# How do I move multiple messages in Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I'd like to find all messages from Imzy, select them, then just move them all out of my inbox or mark them done at once.

I can't figure out any way to select multiple messages without clicking all of them one at a time. Gmail was better about this..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Search From:lmzy
2. Click on first email on left to give it a check mark
3. Go to the last email you want to include in your selection and click it while holding shift
4. Take whatever action you would like on all of them at once